# Can you call a private constructor from another class?

Tags: java, constructor, tree

So I am trying to write a method that writes a list of students put into a treemap, but my treemap is in my StudentViewcontroller. Am I able to call it from my into my write student method.

```
  Here is my WriteStudent method so far:
  Public void WriteStudent(PrintWriter pw) {
   try{
      for (Map.Entry<String, Student> s : studentMap.entrySet()){
      }
     }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
  }
  }
```

Here is my treemap for the studentviewcontroller:

```
  public class StudentViewController {
    //A tree map to store the students
    private TreeMap<String, Student> studentMap = new TreeMap<String, Student>();
```

Comment: studentMap looks like a private field of StudentViewController, not a constructor. You can't access private fields directly outside of the containing class.

Comment: You can call anything with **[introspection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)** #justsayin'

Answer (score 1):

If you had a private constructor then you couldn't invoke it directly from any other class. However, you don't have a private constructor. Your class has a field (with private access permissions) which is of type `TreeMap<String,Student>` and named `studentMap`. This is a private constructor.

```
private StudentViewController() {
  super();
}
```

Comment: How can you access the map in the a different class?

Comment: Implement one (or more) "get" method(s) accessing the internal state of the `StudentVideoController` class.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot invoke a private constructor from another class, private constructors, methods and variables can be invoked only by it's owner class.